# Get details about survey monkey's questions and answers by id

Tags: surveymonkey

survey monkey provides an api to extract responses here

```
https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/get_responses
```

However, the responses map to a question_id along with column, row and/or text for the user response.

How do I go about extracting the question details from the question_id? I was not able to find any documentation for this.

Answer (score 1):

To map this back you need to use the data retrieved via get_survey_details, documented here:

https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/get_survey_details

This will return the question and answer ids so you can map the response back to what was asked.

We have a sample app in the works that will show an example of how to do this in code, however it should be relatively straightforward for you to map things back.

Cheers,

Miles