# How to get survey ID by name in SurveyMonkey

Tags: php, api, surveymonkey

How to get survey ID by name in SurveyMonkey?
This is what is found, but how to convert this into PHP?

curl -i -X POST -H "Authorization:bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN" -H "Content-Type": "application/json" https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/surveys -d '{"title":"New Survey"}'

Here is my basic api call without passing the survey title parameter:

```
<?php
$requestHeaders = array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: Bearer 12345',
);

$url = 'https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/surveys/';
$ch  = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_contactlist);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $requestHeaders);
?>
```

Thanks.

## Solution:

Add

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
```

Comment: What about reading their docs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get the Respondent ID from a Survey Monkey survey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19665652/how-do-you-get-the-respondent-id-from-a-survey-monkey-survey)

Comment: i did, the code curl -i -X POST is grab from their docs.

Comment: You already have the PHP code, just do `curl_exec($ch);` and let us know what the exact issue is then. `-d` parameter equivalent in curl PHP: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25032517/php-curl-setopt-equivalent-to-curl-d

Comment: But i need to pass the param "title:New Survey" for searching/filtering.

Comment: May be you want to put your solution in answer and hit accept it don't bother adding [solved] SO will mark it so. thanks

Comment: ok. will do, thanks for ur advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution: add the following lines：
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);